# Solving a symmetric pair of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, statistical-mechanics

Looking at graphical solutions of

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= - x + cy \\
\dot{y} &= - cy + x,
\end{align}

which for example describe how a [two-level toy system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381254/understanding-the-boltzmann-factor) approaches thermal equilibrium:

[image: octave plot]
<sup>*plot created with Octave (1)*</sup>

one might be tempted to think that

\begin{align}
x(t) &= x_\infty (1-e^{-t/\tau}) + x_0e^{-t/\tau} \\
y(t) &= y_\infty (1-e^{-t/\tau}) + y_0e^{-t/\tau},
\end{align}

would be canonical solutions – provided that $x_\infty + y_\infty = x_0 + y_0$. Then one might want to find out [how $\tau$ depends on $c$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381516/how-to-calculate-the-time-constant-of-a-thermodynamical-system-approaching-equil).

But unfortunately, it seems not to be true:

$$\dot{x} = -\frac{x_\infty-x_0}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau} \neq - x + cy$$

My questions are:

1. Did I make a mistake, and it *is* a solution?
2. If not so: What *are* the canonical solutions to the pair of equations above? Is there a closed form? How do I derive it?

---

(1) Octave code:

```
function dx = f(x,t,c)
   dx(1) = - x(1) + c * x(2);
   dx(2) = -c * x(2) + x(1);
endfunction
g = @(x,t) f(x, t, 5);
xs = lsode(g,[1,2],0:0.01:1);
plot(xs);
```

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the solution. For $t\to\infty$, $x\to2.5$ and $y\to 0.5$, which seem the values of $x_\infty$  and $y_\infty$ in your plot.

Comment: Note that $x+y=\text{const}$ (doesn't change with time), as can be seen from adding the two equations

Comment: @Dog_69: Could you verify that $\dot{x} = -\frac{x_\infty-x_0}{\tau}e^{-t/\tau} \neq - x + cy$? I didn't manage.

Comment: @YuriyS: I am aware of this fact, but it's not a proof that $x(t), y(t)$ are solutions! It's just necessary, not sufficient, is it?

Comment: @HansStricker: Not sure. To be able to verify that you should give the definitions of $x_\infty$ and $y_\infty$.

Comment: Your solution doesn't satisfy this condition

Answer (score 3):

The general solution for this system should be: $$x(t)=C_1 (c+e^{-(1+c)t})+C_2 (c-ce^{-(1+c)t}) \\ y(t)=C_1 (1-e^{-(1+c)t})+C_2 (1+ce^{-(1+c)t})$$ Note that $c$ is inside the brackets in some places, but not others.

$C_1,C_2$ should be found from initial conditions.

Also note that $x+y$ really doesn't depend on $t$ here.

$$x(0)=(1+c)C_1 \\ y(0)=(1+c)C_2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! How did you find the solution? Anyway, the time constant $\tau$ is just $1/(1+c)$. Beautiful.

Comment: @HansStricker, since it's a system of 1st order linear ODEs with constant coefficients, we just need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of its matrix. In this case one of the eigenvalues is $0$, the other is $-1-c$. The eigenvectors are $\{c,1\}$ and $\{-1,1\}$. I'm not sure how to correctly build the solution in this case, so I just used Mathematica to check.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this Physics StackExchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381958/another-way-to-calculate-the-time-constant-of-a-system-approaching-thermal-equil).

Answer (score 3):

It is quite easy to see that
$$
\dot x+\dot y=0\implies x(t)+y(t)=C=x_0+y_0=x_\infty+y_\infty
$$
and
$$
\dot x-c\dot y = -(c+1)(x-cy)
$$
so that for $c\ne -1$ 
$$
x(t)-cy(t)=e^{-(c+1)t}(x_0-cy_0)
$$

The first confirms that the sum is a conserved quantity, and both partial solutions together allow to compute the exact solution.

One might say that this is the eigenvalue-eigenvector approach, but with such a simple structure of the system an explicit computation of them is not necessary.

Comment: @Did : Thanks for the observation. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The general method uses eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but they are not really needed here.

You have, from the second equation, that $x=y'+cy$. So $x'=y''+cy'$. Going back to the first equation, 
$$
y''+cy'+y'+cy=cy.
$$
That is, 
$$
y''+(c+1)y'=0. 
$$
This is first order linear in $y'$, with $y'=y_1\,e^{-(1+c)t}$. So, unles $c=-1$, 
$$
y(t)=-\frac{y_1}{1+c}\,e^{-(1+c)t}+y_0, 
$$
and
\begin{align}
x(t)&=y'+cy=y_1\,e^{-(1+c)t}-\frac {c\,y_1}{1+c}\,e^{-(1+c)t}+c\,y_0\\ \ \\
&=y_1\,\frac{1}{1+c}e^{-(1+c)t}+c\,y_0.
\end{align}
As $y_1$ is an arbitrary constant, we may replace it by $y_1(1+c)$, and we get

> $$
> x(t)=y_1\, e^{-(1+c)t}+c\,y_0,
> $$
>   $$
> y(t)=-y_1\,e^{-(1+c)t}+y_0.
> $$

If you rewrite your candidate solutions as 
$$
x=x_\infty+(x_0-x_\infty)e^{-t/\tau},\ \ \ \ y=y_\infty+(y_0-y_\infty)e^{-t/\tau},
$$
indeed you need $x_0+y_0=x_\infty+y_\infty$, but you also need $x_\infty=cy_\infty$, and $\tau=1/(1+c)$.

---

For the particular case $c=-1$, we have $y''=0$, so $y(t)=y_1\,t+y_0$, and $x(t)=-y_1\, t+y_1-y_0$.

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [this Physics StackExchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381958/another-way-to-calculate-the-time-constant-of-a-system-approaching-thermal-equil).

Answer (score 2):

We have the following pair of coupled linear ODEs

\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= - x + cy\\
\dot{y} &= \,\,\,\, x - cy\\
\end{align}

Such ODEs are very common in chemical kinetics, for example. Note that $\dot{x} + \dot{y} = 0$. Integrating, we obtain $x(t) + y(t) = x_0 + y_0$, where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are initial conditions. Therefore, the 1st ODE can be decoupled from the 2nd ODE as follows

$$\dot{x} = - x + c \left( (x_0 + y_0) - x \right) = - (1+c) \, x + c \,  (x_0 + y_0)$$

or, alternatively,

$$\dot{x} + (1+c) \, x = c \, (x_0 + y_0)$$

which is a standard non-homogeneous 1st order linear ODE. Integrating, I obtained the following

$$x (t) = \color{blue}{\left( \left( \frac{c}{1+c} \right) x_0 + \left( \frac{c}{1+c} \right) y_0 \right) + \left( \left( \frac{1}{1+c} \right) x_0 - \left( \frac{c}{1+c} \right) y_0 \right) e^{- (1+c) \, t}}$$

and, since $y(t) = (x_0 + y_0) - x(t)$,

$$y (t) = \color{blue}{\left( \left( \frac{1}{1+c} \right) x_0 + \left( \frac{1}{1+c} \right) y_0 \right) - \left( \left( \frac{1}{1+c} \right) x_0 - \left( \frac{c}{1+c} \right) y_0 \right) e^{- (1+c) \, t}}$$